# Symfony user migration from old user table to new one

Tags: php, symfony

I migrated some users from an old user table to a new one. Since i migrated those datas user connection doesnt work ("bad credentials").

if i manually change password of a new user (new table) with the command :
php app/console fos:user:change-password myuser mypassword

then i can connect to it.

Any idea ?

Comment: Check `secret` config parameter, as far as i can remember it is used as salt for password encryption. So its value should match one that used for old users creation.

Comment: i dont have any secret conf

Comment: It is in `app/config.yml`, look for `framework.secret` key